In modern HTML, how do you specify the number of rows a table will have (if it's possible)?
Years ago, I remember that with HTML tables, there used to be a way to specify the number of rows a table had, if it was known.  It would help web browsers render the table, which could be helpful if the back-end had a lot of data to send for the table.  I've looked this up on Google recently but don't see a way to specify the number of rows now.  Has that been removed from modern HTML?

Never heard of this, and there are far more efficient ways to work with large data.

I don't think this ever existed. Maybe you're conflating tables with the rows attribute for <textarea> elements.

There's nothing built-in to HTML to do this AFAIK

@Sean No, I specifically remember it being available for HTML tables. Years ago (2003), I used to work with PHP pages that outputted a lot of HTML tables with potentially many rows, and I remember using this.

It might have been something in PHP then, like setting the length of a loop. But I'm pretty confident there's never been an HTML-language feature for that in any previous versions of HTML.

The rows attribute for tables was part of HTML 4 but has been removed in HTML5. Modern HTML does not support specifying the number of rows directly. For handling large datasets efficiently, consider using pagination, lazy loading, or virtualization techniques.

There was not a rows attribute for tables in HTML4.
